# I can't update Nokia Lumia 630

Tags: update, nokia-lumia-630

My brother has Lumia 630, everything works perfectly, but there is no way i can update his phone. Phone says that update is available, but when i tap download button there is just a message "Downloading updates 0%". I left it like that for hour and a half and nothing. I tried to restart it, i took battery out, but nothing helps, it's always the same. Can you help me?
Sorry for my bad English.
http://www.dodaj.rs/f/2Q/nc/4AUUow67/110418088228114877900089.jpg

Comment: Do you have enough phone memory?

Comment: same problem recently with update. still can't install it after a week. 0%.

Answer (score 3):

- You can download update while you are on **WiFi** only.

If you are on Mobile Network, it will just show **"Downloading updates 0%"**, but actually it will wait for Wi-Fi network, as you switch over to a Wi-Fi network, you'll see it downloading.

Answer (score 3):

I have Lumia 620 + Lumia 435.

I've experienced this problem with Lumia 620 (enough free memory storage space and download update via wifi), so I try perform a reset using the hardware keys and problem solved.

[Information about reset using the hardware keys.](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/reset-my-phone)

If after reset the updates still 0%, maybe you must recovery the device using the [Windows Device Recovery Tool.](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=525010)

Don't forget backup the apps, text messages, and more in the cloud beforehand.

Comment: When you use hardware keys, then it's a soft reset.

Comment: @ PChristianFrost
Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if the phone was successful in its latest backups. Windows update will not perform the updates if it cannot perform a backup prior to installation.
2. Try performing (first soft and then hard) reset(s).
3. Ensure that you enough free memory storage space. The need for free space vary depending on update, including some requiring over 2 GB.

Comment: Questions such as *"Have you tried performing (soft and hard) reset(s)?
How much free memory storage space do you have on the phone?"* can be asked as comments. The answer **should provide a solution** to the problem and **should not be asking questions** to the user.

Comment: No, it can't be asked as a comment if I don't have enough reputation. Which I didn't when I posted the reply. But I will rephrase my answer.

Comment: It good to see you edited the answer to help the community. Keep up the work.